# retain dplyr::group_by columns when using tidyr::nest()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

Take the following example in R

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()
```

if we look at the column names of `mtcars_cyl`, we see that `cyl` is no longer included.

```
mtcars_cyl$data[[1]] %>% colnames()

[1] "mpg"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

I was expecting to find some method/option for retaining the `group_by`
columns within `data`, but finding a solution is escaping me. I can understand this might be a niche need. As an example, one might want to create a table of each `group_by` data frame and include `cyl` as a column in that output.

```
library(pander)
mtcars_cyl$data %>% pander::pander()
```

In other cases, when using in combination with `purrr`, one might need to include the `group_by` columns in a function call.

Comment: But, but, but ... `colnames( mtcars_cyl) #[1] "cyl"  "data"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)` instead. This gives a list of data frames.

```r
split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

#> $`4`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#>
#> $`6`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#>
#> $`8`
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I tend to use nest() but also miss the grouping variables.
It is rarely a problem in workflows where the nested data is passed to `purrr::pmap` functions. This work flow allows for subsetting data with nest and apply functions to the nested dataframes including the grouping variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()

# The nested data
mtcars_cyl  

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl data              
  <dbl> <list>            
1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]> 
2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>

# The nested data is summarized and returned with the grouping variable intact
mtcars_cyl %>%
 purrr::pmap_dfr(function(cyl, data) {
    data %>%
      summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
      mutate(cyl = cyl))
    }

# A tibble: 3 x 11
    mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   cyl
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  19.7  183. 122.   3.59  3.12  18.0 0.571 0.429  3.86  3.43     6
2  26.7  105.  82.6  4.07  2.29  19.1 0.909 0.727  4.09  1.55     4
3  15.1  353. 209.   3.23  4.00  16.8 0     0.143  3.29  3.5      8
```

For an indept discussion on `split` vs `nest` see [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pros-and-cons-of-split-vs-nest-with-map-workflows/6492)